# Remove rows based on ifelse statement in Dax

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop, measure, daxstudio

I am trying to create a measure to prevent double counting. The dax code below works fine unless `[LC or USD] = "USD"`. I need to remove the rows when `[LC or USD] = "USD"` holds. How to get around with this? Many thanks in advance.

```
`MyBase = SUM('MyData'[Amount])`


 MyCalculate = 
    CALCULATE(    
        [MyBase],
        KEEPFILTERS('MyData'[Currency] = "USD"),
        KEEPFILTERS('MyData'[Scenario] = "AOP")
    
        )
```

MyData

```
MyData
    LC or USD     Currency Amount
    LC               USD      1
    LC               USD      1
    LC               USD      1
    USD              USD      1
    USD              USD      1
    USD              USD      1
    LC               EUR      1
```

Expected Result

```
 MyData
        LC or USD     Currency Amount
        LC               USD      1
        LC               USD      1
        LC               USD      1
        LC               EUR      1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
Measure = [MyBase](FILTER(MyData, MyData[LC or USD] <> "USD"))
```

[image]

Comment: Awesome, thanks a lot.